# Local machine registry shows wrong IE version

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, version

I have an application that screen scrapes browser pages.

In order to do this I need to get the version of the browser.

```
       public string  GetIEVersion()
        {
            string data = "";
            string sKey;
            RegistryKey dKey;

            sKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer";
            dKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sKey);
            if (dKey != null)
            {
                data = dKey.GetValue("Version").ToString();
            }

            return data;
        }
```

This works fine. However, I have noticed that my machine is returning the incorrect version of IE. Is my registry messed up or is the IE versioning messed up? I don't want to distribute an app looking for the wrong version of IE...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compatibility reasons, Microsoft moved the version data in Internet Explorer 10 and later to try and work around the various quirks people have put into websites over the years to detect IE in webpages and serve specific content.

The Version key's major number has been frozen at 9, with the actual version stored in the minor, build and revision numbers.  The *actual* version can be found in other new keys.

I have Internet Explorer 11 on my machine, and the registry values I have are:

```
Version: 9.11.9600.17239
W2kVersion: 9.11.9600.17239
svcUpdateVersion: 11.0.11
svcVersion: 11.0.9600.17239
```

As you can see, 9 is frozen in the first two, and the rest of the numbers match IE 11 in the *svc* prefixed registry values.

The best solution for your code is to look at *svcVersion* if it is present, and to fall back to *Version* if it is absent.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser().Version`. I guess Microsoft haven't promised what they put in the IE registry, so it's unreliable. I [also read](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785757/wrong-ie-version-data-in-windows-8-registry) that it's for compatibility reasons, so that the version in the registry doesn't go above 9, but it looks like BS to me... So it seems IE10 is 9.10.xxx, IE11 is 9.11.xxx, etc. But who knows what IE12 will put there...